# How do you view the memory space which a local variable is using in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, xcode12

In Visual Studio, I can see a window called the memory window. I can drag an object to the memory window to see how the data is populated.
I'm trying to find the equivalence of memory window in Xcode but have no hit using google.
Please help.

Comment: You can type `po myObject` in the debug console (usually at the bottom pane).

Comment: For more info, see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html or https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheDebugger.html

Comment: @Yonat po does not do what I want, but anyway, thank you for the reply, I found the answer in your provided links, simply right click the variable in the variable list and then click "View Memory of 'variable' " does exactly what I want.